# Why aws cli command has no effect while calling from cron?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cron

Here is my cron jobs list:

```
root@b03fbed2b08d:~# crontab -l
*/3 * * * * S3_BACKUPS_BUCKET=rake-backups /root/dump_psql.sh > /root/logs/cron-2018-01-28T02:24.log
```

Content of dump_psql.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

BACKUP_PATH="/root/backups"
S3_URL="s3://${S3_BACKUPS_BUCKET}"

echo "$(date) Dumping ${POSTGRES_DB} database"
DB_NAME=rake
USER=dbroot
pg_dump -w -c -U $POSTGRES_USER $POSTGRES_DB > "${BACKUP_PATH}/$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M').sql"
echo "$(date) Database dump created"

echo "$(date) Syncing ${BACKUP_PATH} folder with ${S3_URL} as $(whoami)"
/usr/local/bin/aws s3 sync $BACKUP_PATH $S3_URL
echo "$(date) Syncing completed"
```

When I call this script manually It works fine and gives this output:

```
Sun Jan 28 02:51:46 UTC 2018 Dumping rake database
Sun Jan 28 02:51:47 UTC 2018 Database dump created
Sun Jan 28 02:51:47 UTC 2018 Syncing /root/backups folder with s3://rake-backups as root
upload: backups/2018-01-28T02:48.sql to s3://rake-backups/2018-01-28T02:48.sql
upload: backups/2018-01-28T02:51.sql to s3://rake-backups/2018-01-28T02:51.sql
Sun Jan 28 02:51:48 UTC 2018 Syncing completed
```

But cron job output looks like this:

```
Sun Jan 28 02:48:01 UTC 2018 Dumping  database
Sun Jan 28 02:48:01 UTC 2018 Database dump created
Sun Jan 28 02:48:01 UTC 2018 Syncing /root/backups folder with s3://rake-backups as root
Sun Jan 28 02:48:05 UTC 2018 Syncing completed
```

e.g aws sync has no any output (environment variables are in place) and script has no effect - backups are not in the butcket. Where I am wrong?

Comment: Did you go through the debugging help in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info)? It looks like the environment in which the cron command is executed is different and doesn't know about `S3_BACKUPS_BUCKET`.

Comment: But it prints out the line `Syncing /root/backups folder with s3://rake-backups as root`

Comment: Sorry, I meant `POSTGRES_DB`. The first output line, "Dumping database", has a gap there.

Answer (score 2):

You are not checking that your commands are failing. You are not checking for errors. You are also not sending the error output to your log file.

This document describes the return value from AWS commands:

[AWS CLI Return Codes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/return-codes.html)

Modify both your commands to check for failure. Notice the change for the output of pg_dump and the addition of sending the error output to standard output.

```
pg_dump -w -c -U $POSTGRES_USER $POSTGRES_DB -f "${BACKUP_PATH}/$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M').sql" 2>&1

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "$(date) Database dump created"
else
    echo "$(date) Database dump FAILED"
fi

/usr/local/bin/aws s3 sync $BACKUP_PATH $S3_URL 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "$(date) Syncing completed"
else
    echo "$(date) Syncing FAILED"
fi
```

Now review the log file again for error messages and to determine which command failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
i also tried running this from cron its not working but if i manually run it the output is successfully generated`enter code here`

 #!/bin/sh  
/bin/rm -rf /home/user/data.txt
HOME=/home/user/
HOME="/home/user/"
#source /home/user/sc.sh
export AWS_CONFIG_FILE="/root/.aws/config"
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=sbc
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=sbc
#export AWS_ACCESS_KEY=sbc
export AWS_SECRET_KEY=sbc
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
#####################################################################

STARTTIME=$(/bin/date --date='-59 seconds' +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
ENDTIME=$(/bin/date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
/bin/echo $STARTTIME 
/bin/echo $ENDTIME  
aws --version 
###################################################################################

/bin/echo "Memory/RAM Usage of Production Database :" > /home/user/filename.txt 

T=$(aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/RDS --metric-name FreeableMemory --dimensions Name=DBInstanceIdentifier,Value=NAMEOFDB --statistics Maximum --start-time "$STARTTIME" --end-time "$ENDTIME" --period 360)
/bin/echo $T 

TS=$(aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/RDS --metric-name FreeableMemory --dimensions Name=DBInstanceIdentifier,Value=NAMEOFDB --statistics Maximum --start-time "$STARTTIME" --end-time "$ENDTIME" --period 360|/bin/grep Timestamp) >> /home/user/filename.txt
/bin/echo $TS

STARTTIME=$(/bin/date --date='-59 seconds' +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
ENDTIME=$(/bin/date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

FREEM=$(aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/RDS --metric-name FreeableMemory --dimensions Name=DBInstanceIdentifier,Value=NAMEOFDB --statistics Maximum --start-time "$STARTTIME" --end-time "$ENDTIME" --period 360|/bin/grep Maximum|/bin/cut -d: -f 2|/usr/bin/tr -d ','|cut -d. -f 1 ) >> /home/user/filename.txt


FREEMG=$((FREEM/1073741824))
/bin/echo "Memory Utilization = $FREEMG GB /244GB " >> /home/user/filename.txt


###################################################################################################################################################################################
STARTTIME=$(/bin/date --date='-59 seconds' +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
ENDTIME=$(/bin/date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
/bin/echo ""
/bin/echo " Storage Utilization of DriverConnect Production Database Server :" >> /home/user/filename.txt

#echo ""
# Timestamp
TS=$(aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/RDS --metric-name FreeStorageSpace --dimensions Name=DBInstanceIdentifier,Value=NAMEOFDB --statistics Maximum --start-time "$STARTTIME" --end-time "$ENDTIME" --period 360|/bin/grep Timestamp)
/bin/echo $TS  >> /home/user/filename.txt


STARTTIME=$(/bin/date --date='-59 seconds' +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
ENDTIME=$(/bin/date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

# storage utilization in GB

FREEM=$(aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/RDS --metric-name FreeStorageSpace --dimensions Name=DBInstanceIdentifier,Value=NAMEOFDB --statistics Maximum --start-time "$STARTTIME" --end-time "$ENDTIME" --period 360|grep Maximum|/bin/cut -d: -f 2 | /usr/bin/tr -d ','|/bin/cut -d. -f 1 ) >> /home/user/filename.txt
#echo " Occupied Storage of Driverconnect Production Database : " >> /home/user/filename.txt
FREEMG=$((FREEM/1073741824)) 
/bin/echo " Available Storage = $FREEMG Gb/200 Gb" >> /home/user/filename.txt

/bin/echo "################################################################################################################################################################################################"
/bin/echo "################################################################################################################################################################################################"
/bin/echo "################################################################################################################################################################################################"
/bin/echo "################################################################################################################################################################################################"
/bin/echo "################################################################################################################################################################################################"
/bin/echo "################################################################################################################################################################################################"
```